# What is the best way to pay out users so that the receiver pays fees?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-rest-sdk

I am setting up a monthly automated backend process that will transfer money from a central account to thousands of PayPal accounts. The transactions will vary anywhere from $50 to $10,000. The key requirements here are:

1. Receiver must pay the fees
2. No user input required. By this, I mean this process should run without any kind of action on my end (I've noticed that some PayPal integrations require a redirect, approval on the sender side, etc.).

Here are the possible ways I see that you can send money using PayPal:

- Mass Pay

  - Uses classic SOAP APIs. Sender must pay fee, so not an option
- Payouts API

  - Uses new REST APIs. Sender must pay fee, so not an option
- AdaptivePayments

  - Uses classic SOAP API. However, you can force the receiver to pay the fees.
- Rest API Payments

  - See https://developer.paypal.com/docs/rest/api/payments/#payment
  - Uses REST API, which is good.
  - Can you force the receiver to pay the fee?
  - Can this be used without a web browser?

So, it seems like AdaptivePayments or REST API Payments are the only options that could work (there could be more, though). I'd obviously prefer to use the more modern REST API, especially for a new project, but if the functionality that I want to achieve is not possible, then I supposed I will have to use the classic Adaptive Payments option. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only option that allows you to force the receiver to pay the fee is Adaptive Chained Payments, but that would not work for your situation. The type of payment you would be sending would be an Implicit Simple payment, which only allows the sender to pay the fee.

So, your best option would be to use the MassPay API, primarily because of the fee. For US payments, the fee is 2%, capped at $1 which is a significant saving over sending a regular payment at 2.9% + $0.30.

If the fee is that important, you could program it to reduce the amount you send by 2% or $1, whichever is higher.

Comment: So what you are saying is that it's not possible to programmatically send money to someone with PayPal and have the receiver pay the fee?

Comment: Correct. All API situations where you are sending money from your account to other accounts without explicit permission incurs a fee on the sender side.

Comment: How would the receivers give us said explicit permission? And assuming we require them to do so, how would we use the API to make that transaction? If they haven't given explicit permission, will the transaction just fail?

Comment: Explicit permission would still involve a redirect to PayPal so would not be automatic as you are looking for. The answer is that the PayPal system does not support what you are looking for. As explained above, the best option would be to use the MassPay API as it would allow you to process 250 payments at a time and have reduced fees.

Comment: Okay I see. Thank you. In terms of fees, would MassPay be better than Payouts (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/)?

Comment: MassPay is 2% up to max of $1 for domestic. For Payouts, The sender pays Payouts fees at the time of the transaction. US sent domestic Payouts sent over the Payouts API are priced at $0.25 USD flat per transaction. Canadian sent domestic Payouts are priced at $0.32 CAD flat per transaction. US and Canadian sent cross border Payouts are priced just like Mass Payments (2% of each transaction, capped at $20 USD, and $23 CAD respectively). Payouts sent from any other country are priced just like Mass Payments.

Comment: Is the Payouts API something that is easily enabled? I am not located in the U.S. and the Payouts API is not enabled on my account. I am having a hard time getting PayPal to enable it.

Comment: When we use the Payout REST API there is a $0.25 charge for the Sender. But what about the receiver. Does the receiver also have to pay transaction fees on their end ?